# Typescript New Features intelisense

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint, tslint

Is there any way (via tslint/eslint plugins or VS code plugins) to identify if a particular line of code can be updated to latest version of Typescript? e.g.

// Prior to v3.7

```
if (data && data.customer && data.customer.address) {
   const {address} = data.customer
   const fullAddress = `${address.street}, ${address.city}, ${address.state }${address.zipcode}`
}
```

// v3.7 onwards

```
// data access
const address = data?.customer?.address
const fullAddress = `${address?.street}, ${address?.city}, ${address?.state } ${address?.zipcode}`
```

Is there any way to get such intellisence option in vscode or via any npm module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your project do an `npm install -D typescript@latest` to get the latest version of typescript. Or if you project already has typescript that's updated to the version you want, that is fine too

Then in VSCode, open the command palette and select `Typescript: Select Typescript Version`

[image: Select TS Version option]

It will then list all the versions of typescripts that are available for VSCode

[image: Typescript versions]

You can then choose the one you want to use.

Workspace version is the version you install in your project via npm/yarn, VSCode's bundled typescript version has been update to v3.9.3 with VSCode 1.46

Comment: Does that then offer hints or suggestions or any indication what can be improved?

Comment: @VLAZ It depends on the changes made between the versions. On an overall though, yes it does show you the errors in your code and suggestions as you write (linting)

Comment: @tHeSiD, updating doesn't shows the hints to use the latest syntax of Typescript.